# How do I fix Error: adder_out is an unknown type

Tags: verilog

I need an Add operation in my circuit.
I tried designing a simple adder as below:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module adder(
    input [7:0] adder_in1,
    input [7:0] adder_in2,
    output reg [7:0] adder_out
    );
    
    adder_out = adder_in1 + adder_in2;
endmodule
```

But, this code is giving me an error as below. I am really not sure how to correct this code. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix the error is to drop the `reg` declaration, and use the `assign` keyword:

```
module adder(
    input [7:0] adder_in1,
    input [7:0] adder_in2,
    output [7:0] adder_out
    );
    
    assign adder_out = adder_in1 + adder_in2;
endmodule
```

When you make assignments to signals, you either have to be continuous assignments using the `assign` keyword as shown, or they need to be procedural assignments using `always`, `initial`, etc.  In your case, it is simpler to use a continuous assignment.